# out of browser printing in Silverlight with COM

Tags: silverlight, com, silverlight-oob

I want to create a printing solution in Silverlight and be able to print without the print-dialog.
I have seen some similar questions like this, but no one with a sufficient answer.
[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985730/printing-with-silverlight-and-com-interop) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927093/printing-in-silverlight-4-without-print-dialog-out-of-browser-and-elevated-tru)

With this answers in mind, I know that it is possible via COM. But how?
I can't find concrete examples of how to create a document at runtime, and send it with COM to a printer. If possible, I don't want to create a temporary file on disk.

**Update 1**
I mean a Silverlight app running Out of Browser with Elevated Trust.
I can't assume that Office is installed. The content being printed is a PDF file, or a multi-page image file.

Comment: It's not posible, your print action goes trough the browser. Silverlight -> browser -> printer

Comment: @Rumplin: Anything is possible when OOB with Elevated Trust is accessing a COM component.  The question really is, is there a native COM component found on a Windows Platform that enables printing.

Comment: @jwdehaan: What assumptions can be made?  Can the presence of MS Office be assumed?  What min version of windows? etc?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the out of browser text... my bad